# PHP/AJAX: Ajax request to php not working, not putting rows into div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am making a php chat but am having some trouble using ajax to check a mysql database and to put the data into a div. Here are my codes:

HTML

```
<div id="chatbox">
    <div class="chatheader"><div class="chatheadertext">chatheader</div></div>
    <div id="chatcontainer">
        <div class="chatpadding">
            <div id="chatmessages">
                <div class="chat-replies">
                <div class="chat-reply-container">
                    <div class="chat-reply-avatar">
                        <img src="img/default_avatar.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-reply-chat">
                        <span class="chat-reply-author">testuser</span><br>
                        <span class="chat-reply-content">test message goes here</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="form" action="">
          <textarea class="chatchat" id="message" placeholder="Type message here!"></textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$(".chatheader").on("click", function () {
    $("#chatcontainer").slideToggle();
});
$("textarea").keyup(function(e){
 if((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 13) { 
   //The enter button has been pressed
 }
});
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'ajax.php',                 
      data: "",                   
      dataType: 'json',             
      success: function(data)        
      {
        $('#chatmessages').html("<div class='chat-replies'>
                <div class='chat-reply-container'>
                    <div class='chat-reply-avatar'>
                        <img src='img/default_avatar.png'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='chat-reply-chat'>
                        <span class='chat-reply-author'>testuser</span><br>
                        <span class='chat-reply-content'>test message goes here</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>");
      } 
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','chat');
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `messages`");
$msgnum = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$array = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
  echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

So basically what I am trying to do is use ajax to contact the php file which will then check the mysql database for tables and encode them to json, on the index page, the chatbox is supposed to come up by the first javascript function but it's not sliding up.  know that it is the ajax that is doing this, specifically the `$('#chatmessages').html();` line. When I remove the code from that line, the chatbox comes up but is empty inside. What am I doing wrong, how would I do it so that when it contacts, for each row that is found in the database, it echoes

```
<div class='chat-replies'>
                <div class='chat-reply-container'>
                    <div class='chat-reply-avatar'>
                        <img src='img/default_avatar.png'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='chat-reply-chat'>
                        <span class='chat-reply-author'>testuser</span><br>
                        <span class='chat-reply-content'>test message goes here</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

So if there are like 50 rows in the database, it would echo that script for each of the rows, and there would be an `overflow-y:scroll` on the `<div id="chatmessages">` so it doesn't overflow. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Comment: when ajax call is made ? on which event?

Answer (score 0):

If you've json data in success callback of your AJAX call, you can iterate through all records and append each record to your chat div

```
 success: function(data)        
          {
           $.each(data,function(index,dataRecord){
           document.getElementById('chatmessages').innerHTML +="html content goes here";
           });
           //scroll down your div,make sure you should have propery, overflow-y:scroll
          document.getElementById('chatmessages').scrollTop=100000;
         }
```

Hope this will help,
Thanks

Comment: The chatbox won't toggle when I add the html code to the script, tried it with this script, but the chat doesn't open at all with it.

Comment: show your chat div in success callback as first statement. $("#chatmessages").show()